# Timeout Azure Function if trigger other azure function

Tags: node.js, azure, timeout, azure-functions

I am new Azure function. I want to call the Azure function which will trigger another Azure function. I have written bellow code but its giving me timeout. The code written in node js. 
Please suggest what to do.

```
 module.exports = async function (context, req, callback) {
   UtilityAccountNumber=req.body.UtilityAccountNumber.split(',');
    if(UtilityAccountNumber=='' || typeof UtilityAccountNumber==='undefined' || !(Array.isArray(UtilityAccountNumber) && UtilityAccountNumber.length) ){
        response={
            status: 0,
            message:"Please provide utility acccount number."
        };
    else{
        if(UtilityAccountNumber.length){
            for(let accountNo of UtilityAccountNumber){
                try
                {

                var options = {
                 host: process.env.API_HOST,
                 port: process.env.PORT,
                 path: '/api/'+process.env.WEBSCRAPERMASTER,
                 method: 'POST'
                };


                var myreq = http.request(options, function(res) {

                });                                

                myreq.end();

                }
                catch (ex) // if failed
                {
                await logHTTPErrorResponse(ex, huId);
                console.error(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: response
    };


};
```

Comment: Max timeout possible in Azure Functions is 10 minutes. Your use case sounds like a good fit for Durable functions which are extensions to Azure Functions. Have you explored them already? If not, these links might help. Getting started with Durable functions - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode] also take a look into function chaining [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence?tabs=csharp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code logic may be stuck at some point, so it gives you timeout.(Azure function has a default timeout limit.) I think the function chain of azure durable function fully meets your requirements, and you are using nodejs, so azure durable function is supported.

Please have a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence?tabs=javascript